how to solve 'Error: Command "npm run build" exited with SIGABRT' when deploying Next.js app on Vercel?
The error takes place after I set up nextjs.config.mjs to make plaiceholder work with Next.js:
import withPlaiceholder from '@plaiceholder/next';

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: "cdn.sanity.io"

            }
        ]
    },
    experimental: {
        taint: true,
    },
};

export default withPlaiceholder(nextConfig);

I tried transpiling the @plaiceholder/next and sharp packages as well as rewriting a piece of webpack config as you can see below, unfortunately it didn't work.
const nextConfig = {
    webpack(config) {
        const sharpRule = {
          sharp: 'commonjs sharp',
        };

        if (Array.isArray(config.externals)) {
          config.externals.push(sharpRule);
        } else {
          config.externals = {
            ...config.externals,
            ...sharpRule,
          };
        }

        return config;
      },
    transpilePackages: ['@plaiceholder/next', "sharp"],
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: "cdn.sanity.io"

            }
        ]
    },
    experimental: {
        taint: true,
    },
};

